# grails: add context to embedded tomcat in development

Tags: grails

In production I have setup an external folder to upload and display
images from by editing server.xml:

```
<Service name="Catalina">

   <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
             connectionTimeout="20000"
             URIEncoding="UTF-8"
             redirectPort="443" />

   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

     <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
        resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

     <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
       xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

       <Context docBase="/opt/winmail_storage/imgs" path="/imgs"/>

     </Host>
   </Engine>
 </Service>
```

I am trying to do the same thing in development by editing _Events.groovy :

```
eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
       def ctx = tomcat.addContext("/imgs" , "/tmp/images")
}
```

I also tried

```
eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
       def ctx = tomcat.addContext("/appName/imgs" , "/tmp/images")
}
```

this is not working, the imgs directory is not accessible via :
http://host/appName/imgs  any idea how I can do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally got it thanks to the grails mailing list:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->

def context = tomcat.addWebapp('/acrm/imgs' , '/tmp/images')
def loader = new WebappLoader(tomcat.class.classLoader)
loader.addRepository(new File('/home/mohadib/workspace/acrm/lib').toURI().toURL().toString())
loader.container = context
context.loader = loader
}
```